# Vercel Deployment Edge Function error: EDGE_FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel, edge-function

when I'm trying to POST something to my Edge Function on Vercel Deployment I get the following error:

> [POST] /api/openai reason=EDGE_FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED, status=500,
> user_error=true
>
> TypeError: Illegal invocation at app/api/openai/route.ts:12:36

My Edge Function file:

```
import { OpenAIStream, OpenAIStreamPayload } from "@/utils/OpenAIStream";

if (!process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY) {
  throw new Error("Missing env var from OpenAI");
}

export const config = {
  runtime: "edge",
};

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { prompt } = (await request.json()) as {
    prompt?: string;
  };

  if (!prompt) {
    return new Response("No prompt in the request", { status: 400 });
  }

  //OpenAI logic....
  return new Response();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that has been fixed in the latest `13.3.x`. Workaround can be found here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46337#issuecomment-1478613133